# How to select the images in carousel using ImagePicker?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a carousel in which the images are storing dynamically. I want to select multiple images and capture the selected images. Now whichever images I've selected want to display on another page for this I used ImagePicker. Multiple images are displaying because I am using a map inside the map. I tried very much but I couldn't solve this. Please help. Here are my code and output.

```
import React from "react";
import Carousel, { Dots } from '@brainhubeu/react-carousel';
import '@brainhubeu/react-carousel/lib/style.css';
import ImagePicker from 'react-image-picker';

class CropSelection extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
super(props)
this.state = {
  imgslides: [],
  img: []
}
this.onPick = this.onPick.bind(this);
}
componentDidMount = () => {

fetch('http://localhost/fruit_api/carousel_api.php')

.then((response) => response.json())

.then(data => {
  console.log(data)

  let slides = data.data.map((pic, key) => {
    return(
      <div className="images-data">

        {/* <ImagePicker 
            images={data.data.map((image, i) => ({src: image.img, value: i}))}
            onPick={this.onPickImages}
            multiple
        /> */}
        <img src = {pic.img} alt="" /> 
      </div>
    )
  })
  this.setState({
    imgslides: slides
  })
  // console.log("state", this.state.slides);
})
.then(function(response){
  console.log(response)
})

.catch(function(response){
  console.error(response)
});

}
onPick = (image) => {
 this.setState({image})
}
render() {

return (
  <div className="caurosel-div">

   <Carousel
    arrows
    slidesPerScroll={1}
    slidesPerPage={5}
    // value={this.state.value}
    slides = {this.state.imgslides} 
    onChange={this.onchange}
    >
      {/* <ImagePicker
        images = {this.state.imgslides}
        multiple
      /> */}
    {/* <button type="button" onClick={() => console.log(this.state.img)}>OK</button> */}

     </Carousel> 

  );
 }
}


export default CropSelection;
```

[image: output]

Comment: Do you want to select more than 1 image in the carousel?

Comment: Yeah..I am trying to select more than one

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is when you try to render ImagePicker inside Carousel, as both the components expect and render differently you don't see the render happening. Carousel component expects  but your ImagePicker returns  with children as .

If you are trying to use, ImagePicker just to select the images, the it can be done directly using Carousel itself and little custom css. From your imagelist, you can render images inside carousel, assign an onclick for each of the img to obtain the selected image and change the classname to show the selected image effect similar to Image Picker.

Here is a working example of implementing the above - https://react-n57tkq.stackblitz.io/

Code - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-n57tkq?file=index.js

In the example above, a single image is being selected. If you want to have more than one image as part of selection process, then make it as an array of selected images. You can use this array to display the selected images in your other component.

Hope this helps!

D

Comment: Thank you..I'll try this and let you know

Comment: I am not getting the border of the selected fruit. What should I do for this?